# Can Google Cloud Storage write byte ranges into an existing object?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Google Cloud Storage API doesn't appear to support writing byte ranges. Are there any workarounds?

I'm considering a design that would use a storage object to read and write 1000's of fixed byte ranges, where each range is a data record (~1kb) in a partitioned schema.

For example, each range might represent data for a day of the year from a given start time, and the client would obtain the data for a given range of days by reading at an offset.

I can see that I could use a storage object for each record, and will need to consider the impact batch limits (100 calls) will have on performance when reading the many small records.

Of course, it may be that cloud storage is the wrong approach and a database would handle this requirement better. However, it seems that storage scales very well (for parallel reads and writes) and would otherwise work well for long-term storage of bulk data that needs to only answer a very specific type of query (i.e. general purpose database seems unnecessary overhead).

**Reference**

[Objects: insert](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/insert)

[A Case for Packing and Indexing in Cloud File Systems](https://saurabhkadekodi.github.io/packing.pdf)

Comment: As far as I know an object blob is immutable once you write it to GCS.

Comment: Please elaborate on your use case as to what you are trying to achieve, for appropriate workaround suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I've updated the question re example use.

Comment: Further to this, I've added a paper on motivations for storing byte ranges in cloud storage to references.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objects are immutable and must be written sequentially from start to finish.

If you're looking for a way to do parallel uploads you can use [Object Composition](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/composite-objects) or [Multipart Uploads](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/multipart-uploads).

Comment: Thanks for confirming the official capabilities. I should probably elaborate on the use re workarounds. Will add that to question.

Comment: Reading your updated question, it sounds like you want to be able to overwrite thousands of fixed byte ranges. You could achieve something like that by building thousands of separate objects and composing a new object from them (and recomposing every time you update any of them), but that has 2 downsides: (1) You'll be charged for the component objects as well as the composite object, effectively doubling your storage costs. (2) Google Cloud Storage imposes a [limit](https://cloud.google.com/storage/quotas#objects) of one update per second to an individual object.

Comment: Hi Mike. Thanks for pointing to the one-update-per-second limit for objects. Combined with 32 object limit for composing, this seems unworkable. Typical workload is bulk loading ~100k records of ~1kb written into partitions on id and day-of-year. Reading involves getting a whole partition (or range) for ~10 ids, which I think could be achieved using bulk requests and range header. This morning, I'm looking at preparing partition files externally in the ETL system and uploading a single reconstructed partition into storage.

Comment: Thanks Mike and others for input. In the end, I chose to use cloud storage for long term storage of snapshots, and move selected snapshots into cloud memorystore for access to individual records by id. I think reading *and* writing byte ranges to storage objects remains an interesting idea and could simplify certain types of app.

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud Storage is the Object Storage managed service for Google Cloud Platform. Unlike a block storage or file system storage, objects stored are immutable.

As mentioned in the [Official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/key-terms),

*Objects are immutable, which means that an uploaded object cannot change throughout its storage lifetime. An object's storage lifetime is the time between successful object creation, such as uploading, and successful object deletion. In practice, this means that you cannot make incremental changes to objects, such as append operations or truncate operations. However, it is possible to replace objects that are stored in Cloud Storage, and doing so happens atomically: until the new upload completes, the old version of the object is served to readers, and after the upload completes the new version of the object is served to readers. So a single replacement operation simply marks the end of one immutable object's lifetime and the beginning of a new immutable object's lifetime.*

As a workaround, you can try the concept of **Object Composition**,

```
gsutil compose gs://bucket/source_obj1 [gs://bucket/source_obj2 ...] gs://bucket/composite_obj
```

This operation basically **concatenates the contents of a number of objects in the same bucket under a new name (as an example, cat file1 file2 > newfile) but without re-writing data**.
So you could create a new object, upload the contents to append to it, close and subsequently compose this new piece at the end of your main file.
However, there is a limit (currently 32) to the number of components that can be composed in a single operation.

You may explore more on Object Composition from the [Compose Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/compose) and [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/compose).

Comment: Thank you, that's really helpful. The workaround might work for others, but the limit of 32 items doesn't work for me as I'm interested in reading and writing 1000's of byte ranges.